# How can I get a summary from a view into another view?

Tags: views

There are a few views that gather and analyze data from several nodes to form a budget based on their workflow. These views have a "total" area (defined as a custom content field within the view), which calculates the the total amount of money allocated by each node.
[image]
Each node is also associated with a team object, and what I want to accomplish is to get the "total" field from each view to act as a column in another view, so we can see how much money was allocated/spent with each team.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do looks more or less like this:

```
Team Number | View 1 Total | View 2 Total | View 3 Total | Total of the Totals
1           |          $33 |         $-10 |         $-20 |                  $3
2           |          $50 |         $-15 |         $-10 |                 $25
```

I've looked into trying [views-field-view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view), but I haven't been able to find an option that allows me to select that specific row, which is created with a summarized table as the format. This is the same across all three views. How would I go about achieving this, with either views-field-view or another module? Or should I just go ahead and do this with a panel using custom PHP code?

Comment: do you got some advance?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer in some ways yes, but in others, not really. I haven't actually had much time to work on it recently, but do you know of any good tutorials for the modules you mentioned?

Comment: I just know http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_aggregator/plain/README.txt?id=refs/heads/7.x-1.x and http://drupal.org/node/359981

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module with the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) or with the [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc) module.

**Views Calc:**

> Adds simple calculations to a views table. You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug
>   in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies
>   numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines
>   calculated rows).

**Views Aggregator Plus:**

> In addition to what Views and Views Calc do, this module:
>
> - enumerates group members
> - produces tallies, i.e. textual histograms
> - aggregates on Views PHP code-snippet evalutations
> - can filter out result rows on regexp patterns
> - gives you sorting on Views' Math expressions
> - can process Webform submissions
> - lets you add your own custom aggregation functions
>
> ... and it puts summary statistics at the bottom of your aggregated
>   table as well!